# SQL Query with COUNT, Having Count >1, display full details of duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, having

I have a table like :

```
name  employment_Status  email
----     ----             -----
David     E              David@email.com
John      U              John@email.com
Michael   E              Michael@email.com
Steve     E              Michael@email.com
James     U              David@email.com
Mary      U              Mary@email.com
Beth      E              Beth@email.com
```

I started by selecting `email` and `count(email)`:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) AS emailCount
FROM Table
GROUP BY email
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 );
```

The problem occurred when I tried to include `name` as well:

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(email) AS emailCount
FROM Table
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 );
```

I would like to find all people with a duplicate email addresses, (only where both people are employed (E)). However it is returning zero results.

I'd like to be able to display all information for people with duplicate emails, and having `employment_Status` `E`. If two people have the same email, but one or both is Unemployed (U), then just ignore.

Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.employeed = 'E' and
     exists (select 1
             from t t2
             where t2.email = t.email and t2.employeed = 'E' and
                   t2.name <> t.name
            );
```

Note that this assumes that `name` (or at least `name`/`email`) is unique.

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by t.email) as cnt
      from t
      where t.employeed = 'E'
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use your query as a subquery in FROM clause, and JOIN the result with the main table.

```
SELECT t.*, d.emailCount
FROM (
    SELECT email, employment_Status, COUNT(*) AS emailCount
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY email
    WHERE employment_Status = 'E'
    HAVING emailCount > 1 
) d
JOIN my_table t USING(email, employment_Status)
```

You could also use [`GROUP_CONCAT(name)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), if you are fine getiing the names in a (comma) separated string:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS emailCount, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names
FROM my_table
GROUP BY email
WHERE employment_Status = 'E'
HAVING emailCount > 1
```

The result for your sample data would be:

```
email               emailCount    names
-----------------------------------------------
Michael@email.com       2         Michael,Steve
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions. They have both been very helpful.